# Rails associations using an array as the foreign_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, associations

I am looking to create an association where a model can be created and owned by three different entities but also references the other two entities.

For example, I have a **performance** model where three different types of models can create a performance: **venue**, **artist**, **band**. However, the performance also needs to reference the other two e.g if a venue creates a performance, it needs to list an artist or a band that will be performing. And if an artist creates a performance, then the artist needs to put a venue where he/she will be performing.

So I am starting with something like this:

```
class CreatePerformances < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :performances, id: :uuid do |t|
      t.belongs_to :venue, index: true
      t.belongs_to :artist, index: true
      t.belongs_to :band, index: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

However, if a venue owner creates a performance and has two separate bands performing then I would need to have an array of bands in the **band_id column**. But when I do that (`t.belongs_to :band, type: :uuid, array: true, default: [], index: true`) and add a band to the `band_id` array and then do `band.performances` I get: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  malformed array literal:`

Can I make an association column an array and still be able to use the Rails association features or is that not possible or even bad practice, and if so how?

Also, I am using postgresql and if you have a more elegant ways of doing the above that would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess it's better to use a has_many relationship.

If a performance can have many bands playing then it does not "belongs to" a band, it "has many" bands.

So you may use a "has and belongs to many" or a "has many :through" relationship between performances and bands. Check the differences here https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many

The easiest of the two to configure is HABTM:

```
class Band
  has_and_belongs_to_many :performances

class Performance
  has_and_belongs_to_many :bands
```

You need a table, so add a miration that does this:

```
create_table :bands_performances, id: false do |t|
  t.references :band, index: true
  t.references :performance, index: true
end
```

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#creating-join-tables-for-has-and-belongs-to-many-associations

Check the guide, if you need extra fields you may need a join model and use has_many :through. You know the context better than anyone.

Comment: This is a good answer and should most likely be accepted, however, keep in mind that `has_many :through` has essentially replaced `has_and_belongs_to_many`

Comment: @MarkMerritt it's not the first time I read someone saying that HMT replaces HABTM, but I can't find any oficial statement about that. The official rails guides shows both options with a specific section on when you may preferer one over the other. I know HMT can handle the same use cases of HABTM and more and I've put that on my answer, but I've never read something official saying one should prefer HMT over HABTM on *every case*. Do you have any reference on that?

Comment: @MarkMerritt I don't think that means that it's something official (it's just a famous book and that particularly is a quote from a blog when Rails 1.1 came out, the documentation does not reflect that statement), and before that, on the `has_and_belongs_to_many` section it says that it's fine to use HABTM on the cases the rails guide point out (if the association does not require extra attributes). I think saying that one should not use HABTM *on any case* because HMT *replaces* it is misleading, those are both valid on different contexts (that's why I've put the last link on my answer)

Comment: @MarkMerritt it is relevant, someone reading "HMT has essentially replaced HABTM" may think he should *never* use HABTM, but the documentation clearly states that you can use it just fine in some simple scenarios. The only benefit I see is that it's easier to configure for a beginner (without the need of an explicit jon model). Anyway, like I said in my answer, I'm suggesting both options since I don't know the context and gave the link to read on the differences, I'm not saying someone should use one over the other.